# Origin of the zillion offers to light one cigarette

Tags: reference, trope

In the film [All That Jazz](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078754/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0), the character Michelle was played by the actress Erzsebet Foldi when she was around 13 years old.

[image]

In a fantasy sequence late in the film, Michelle performs the song "[Some Of These Days](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5Hb1wKsbBc)". At the beginning of this sequence, Michelle holds an unlit cigarette in a long holder, and a few cigarette lighters are immediately offered.

It seems to me that this whole production, with the slinky sequined dress and the feather boa, recreates a moment in some other film. But the eagerly offered cigarette lighters seem almost a film cliché. I suppose that it must have been men trying to ingratiate themselves with a beautiful woman, rather than women trying to light the cigarette of a little girl. But (much like Rogers and Hart) I can't remember where or when.

Is this production a reference to another similar scene in another film? And where does the business with the cigarette come from?

Comment: Cigarette lighters have often been used in films as tools of crime, deception, exoneration, investigation and manipulation. They are often represented as devices that drive the narrative.

Comment: [TVTropes doesn't have an entry for it](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheSmokingSection)

Comment: I've got a mental image of bugs bunny in a dress, but google is not being kind to me.

Comment: Yes, but Bugs Bunny was satirising the trope, which was already well known.

Comment: @Chenmunka - The offer of a light was the trope, the zillion offers is the satire.

Comment: @OrangeDog I followed your link and looked around. "Favors For The Sexy" seemed relevant, with one example in which a newly single woman suddenly receives a lot of gifts. But I'm imagining something so visual. I guess the idea of the woman with the cigarette is that every man in the world would react the same way, as shown by the quickness of everyone who happen to be at hand at the crucial and unforeseeable moment.

Answer (score 2):

> Where does the business with the cigarette come from?

**About women**:

*Smoke signals [was] once a symbol of glamour on screen<sup>1</sup>* says the [LA Times](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1992-01-04-ca-1334-story.html). According to Wikipedia's [torches of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torches_of_Freedom), *before the twentieth century smoking was seen as a habit that was corrupt and inappropriate for women. In the 19th century, cigarettes were perceived as props of "fallen women" and prostitutes.*

Cigarettes were firstly for upper-class rich males. Typically, smoking diffused through populations, establishing itself first among elite men, and working down class and status hierarchies and through the population until it reached women (through advertising).

Then came the rebellion<sup>2</sup>. Cigarettes became a way for women to challenge social norms and fight for equal rights as men. Eventually for women the cigarette came to symbolize "rebellious independence, glamour, seduction and sexual allure for both feminists and flappers".

**About men**:

> But the eagerly offered cigarette lighters seem almost a film cliché

It is. "*Cigarettes symbolize adulthood, and adulthood, from the viewpoint of children, symbolizes power.*" ([Smoking and symbolism - Oxford Academic](https://academic.oup.com/her/article/16/2/131/644584)).
Usually, the tough guy, the bad guy, the hero, the **man** is smoking. Think of Mickael Corleone lighting Enzo's cigarette in front of the hospital where the Don is. It dark, cold, dangerous. Villains are coming. Enzo is scared, shaking, can barely hold his cigarette. Mickael is just calm and facing the danger without any trace of fear. That makes him powerful. This scene makes him iconic.

*Movie directors and actors use smoking to project character traits typically seen in tobacco advertising: **toughness, rebelliousness, and sexiness**.* [Cigarette smoking and perception of a movie character - JAMA](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamapediatrics/fullarticle/380691)

---

**To summarize:** the smoking girl is open-minded, sexy and strong, the cigarette is an opener to the conversation, and **the man** gets the girl. Does the girl choose the man when she chooses the lighter? They like to think that, like the peacock making the wheel.

---

> Is this production a reference to another similar scene in another film?

A particular similar one? Like a tribute? Couldn't think of one or find it. But in many other movies you can see a man lighting a woman's cigarette. Maybe not exactly the same scene, on stage or in a cabaret, but it's the image of the *femme fatale* (is *hot vixen* an appropriate translation?), strong, independant, rebel personality.

---

<sup>1. [Marlene Dietrich](https://www.alamyimages.fr/photos-images/marlene-dietrich-cigarette.html?sortBy=relevant) or [Lauren Bacall](https://www.alamyimages.fr/photos-images/lauren-bacall-cigarette.html?sortBy=relevant) smoking a cigarette. Some further reading about [the symbolic power of women smoking on screen](https://lesbiap.art/home/smoking-section-or-the-symbolic-power-of-women-smoking-on-screen) and watch "*how cigarettes became a symbol of power in film*":</sup>

<sup>2. [Torches of Freedom campaign](https://biblio.uottawa.ca/omeka2/jmccutcheon/exhibits/show/american-women-in-tobacco-adve/torches-of-freedom-campaign): a short and interesting article about women and smoking.</sup>

Comment: The question is not what smoking cigarettes mean (which you're spot on about), but the specific situation of men competing to light a woman's cigarette.

Comment: I've clarified, seemed obvious to me, but thanks for pointing out, makes it more clear now I think :)

Comment: Do you know of any scene like I'm imagining, in which someone takes out a cigarette and is suddenly surrounded by burning matches and lighters? I had such a strong feeling that it was Marilyn Monroe that I even watched Madonna's "Material Girl" video -- with the sound off -- for the first time since the 1980's. But no luck.

Comment: This still doesn't address the question.  The fact of smoking is irrelevant to the trope.

Comment: If you have 1 person offering a lighter, or 3 or 100, don't you think the more you have, the more you're wooed? Especially if you see all lights as stars? And it's rooted in the way people has seen smoking for decades. I wanted to give some background too.

Comment: @OldPadawan I'm not sure I'm following you. I guess that if I were the beauty and one man offered a light, I might think that he was special -- the one gentleman or the one kind soul or the one person attracted to me in a big world of cads or meanies or people repelled by me. Having everyone offer makes each of them ordinary. Also, of course, it makes the moment funny rather than possibly friendly or romantic or completely ordinary. Even in reality I've often held doors open for people or passed through doors held open for me, and it's completely ordinary and not at all striking.